# Python TimeDelta Add Day to Supplied Argument

Tags: datetime, python-2.7

Not sure how to approach this one.

User supplies an argument, ie, program.exe '2001-08-12'

I need to add a single day to that argument - this will represent a date range for another part of the program. I am aware that you can add or subtract from the current day but how does one add or subtract from a user supplied date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import datetime
...
date=time.strptime(argv[1], "%y-%m-%d");
newdate=date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get ValueError: time data '2001-08-12' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'

Comment: Capitalizing the %Y resolved that error, however, I now receive this:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Answer (score 2):

Arnauds Code is valid,Just see how to use it :) :-

```
>>> import datetime
>>> x=datetime.datetime.strptime('2001-08-12','%Y-%m-%d')
>>> newdate=x + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> newdate
datetime.datetime(2001, 8, 13, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Comment: I receive AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta' with yours :) i'm sure its just me missing something...

Comment: Had you done `import datetime` if not try `from datetime import timedelta`

Comment: I believe the way I am importing is incorrect. Testing this outside of the application works - its probably being broken by another portion of the code that uses the datetime.now()  - be back in a sec

Comment: As I thought! Okay yes, code works great but I had to replace two instances of timestamp=datetime.now() with timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow() -> I am guessing the import (or import from) requirements it needed conflicted with the import requirements the above script wanted? Anyhow it works! Appreciate the help (marking answer)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's what I've got:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
user_input = sys.argv[1]                # Get their date string

year_month_day = user_input.split('-')  # Split it into [year, month, day]

year = int(year_month_day[0])
month = int(year_month_day[1])
day = int(year_month_day[2])

date_plus_a_day = datetime(year, month, day+1)
```

I understand this is a little long, but I wanted to make sure each step was clear. I'll leave shortening it up to you if you want it shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, this would put the day out of range in a month if say the user input was 2001-07-31 ? > date_plus_a_day would be 2001-07-32 if I am not mistaken, yes?

Comment: Good comment. Yes you are right. For this code to work fully you would need a series of checks verifying that overlap does not occur, and if it does, handling it.